# Windows/React Native can't create ADB Bridge error

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to run a React Native App on Windows but I'm getting a weird error.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Could not create ADB Bridge. ADB location: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

I've seen similar solutions to this problem but they seemed geared towards Mac Users. If anyone can give me a working solution that will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  emulator then start emulator before run app..

Do you have skype installed on your PC?  if yes then it might using 8081 port.

uninstall skype and try it